# How to share volume mounts between different cron jobs in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, kubernetes-cronjob, mounted-volumes

I have unique use case, where i need to run a bunch of cron jobs every minute. These cron jobs have numerous volume mounts defined within them (50 or so) via PVCs and PVs. Clearly mounting and un-mounting during every cron run is inefficient. Given the constraint that I cannot move away from cron jobs for my use-case, is there a better way to share the volume mounts?

Thanks
K

Comment: If you care about mount efficiency, use remote storage like NFS or S3

Comment: When you talk about running cron jobs, do you mean you created a CronJob resource? I am not [ still ;-) ] a Kubernetes specialist, but my impression is that having Jobs running every minute could be inefficient in any way because you're going to create containers for them every minute. **If you are having performance problems,** isn't it better to create a long-running pod with real Linux cron jobs in it would be more efficient? (Again, no specialist here.)

Comment: What you can do depends on what is your use case. Unfortunately not much can be done with PVC/PV itself. No matter if you choose to use remote sotrage solutions, like NFS, mounting and unmounting will still be a bottleneck. Instead, you may want to look into tools like Kafka, or Longhorn - but again, this strongly depends on your use case.